# How to increase anti alias/blur on sIFR text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, sifr

I'm using sIFR to make my text nice and smooth, but I would like it to be slightly more blurred/smooth/anti aliased than it currently is. How would I do that?

I used a sIFR swf generator from http://www.sifrgenerator.com/ and pretty much followed their instructions, but the text isn't appearing as smooth as I wanted, although it is a definite improvement.

How would I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it seems that the topic is still of interest, even though it is true that there is no current version of sifr. I agree that the method has ist limitations but if you take a closer look at HOW current browsers render web-fonts, no one who wants to make a goo looking website can really use it by today or in the near future. Legalities aside - which is dangerous in itself.
And if you ask me the only point of using 'special' fonts is to make your pages look better and better readable, which you don't do at all by using web-fonts. Most of them are also quite large in site, as they carry a lot of information (hints etc.) one can do quite well without (as flash proves).
So I would say that an updated sifr system (as3 and probably jQuery) still would be of great use. As I cannot find something like that I right now thinking about starting such a project.
Anyone would care to join?
BTW: There are some attempts like the jQuery sIFR plugin and sIFR lite one might use as starting points.

M

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but sIFR isn't really used anymore. Font-embedding with CSS @font-face is the preferred way to deliver custom fonts. Check out:

http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

For some free fonts to embed.

Comment: -1: sIFR allows you to embed fonts where the licence restricts you to only embed the font in an Adobe Flash file. While I agree that `@font-face` is the way to go in the future, until WOFF becomes more mainstream and font licences gets updated, sIFR is still relevant today.

Comment: @Taimur Yes, #font-face (when correctly implemented) works on all major browsers in use today.

Comment: @Andrew Moore sIFR has a lot of issues; the main ones being that it's not being actively developed anymore and that it depends on Flash (and therefore doesn't work on an iOS devices). To recommend someone implement sIFR today is myopic & irresponsible.

Comment: @Tim Hettler: And embedding fonts using `@font-face` when the font you chose doesn't allow it is illegal. If you need to use a typeface due to corporate identity guidelines or other reason, need to have dynamic headlines, and can't embed it with `@font-face` due to font licensing issues, sIFR is the only option.

Comment: Legality is beyond the scope of this issue - I have no idea what font is being used. I'm just pointing out that sIFR is an outdated way to embed fonts and that there's an easier and more robust way to do it.